# Relative paths are not loading when used in html after using RewriteRule in htaccess

Tags: css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I searched online for a solution.

I have my web application files on `http://localhost.com/exampleFolder/` I have updated smoe rewriterule into my .htaccess file as below

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .?- [S=3]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)?(.*)$ index.php?aa=$1&bb=$2&cc=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)?(.*)$ index.php?aa=$1&bb=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)?(.*)$ index.php?aa=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

I have updated the base value in html as

```
<base href="//localhost/exampleFolder/" />
```

and I am linking my css as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="all" />
```

When I debug the code, and mouse hover on the href i am getting

```
localhost/exampleFolder/css/style.css
```

but still, CSS is not at all loading.
When I use direct path even then I get the index.php

I guess its because of the rewrite rules I have used. Please help me I have spent weeks to understand htaccess. I did find similar questions on stack overflow but none of them were helpful for me.

thanks in advance

Comment: I understand that when you write : ^(.*) in beginning of your rule, it will redirect any url you request  to index.php?aa= . you need to redirect your index.php to one virtual folder for instance like : ^blog/

Comment: Thank you so much Cyrillus, 

I actually have more than 10 pages that were included using php on index.php after getting the aa value,

I didnot want to right 30 lines of script that was the other reason i took the above step..

can you please suggest me one more hint..

Comment: okay, if you take exemple above, any url with blog/xx/xx/xx will rebuild your url like this (on server side, note on yours) : index.php?=aa&XX=&XX=&XX= any url that do not start so, won't be redirected. If aa means your blog, keep blog for them, and produce other pattern for the other , ?bb , ?cc (what ever you use. :)

Comment: I added /app/ to my url to open the index file so, my final path was http://localhost/sandboxapp/app/. It worked well and loaded the css also, 

then I thought to put a header location in index.php which is redirecting continous loop. Do I have to use pregmatch to add /app/ to the path.  Is there any other right way for the same..

Comment: You saved my life Cyrillus.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best after getting help by Cyrillus

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .?- [S=3]
RewriteRule ^app/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)?(.*)$ index.php?aa=$1&bb=$2&cc=$3 [NE,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^app/(.*)/(.*)?(.*)$ index.php?aa=$1&bb=$2 [NE,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^app/(.*)?(.*)$ index.php?aa=$1 [NE,L,QSA]
```

final output:

```
url: example.com/app/question/100/relative-paths
PHP: example.com/index.php?aa=question&bb=100&cc=relative-paths
```

thanks to Cyrillus